# Multiline button in winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, button

How can I create a multiline button in winAPI (\n or even \r\n doesn't work). Here is the code:

```
HWND hPrzyciskoff = CreateWindowEx( 0, "BUTTON", "Play offline", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 410, 550, 380, 25, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add [`BS_MULTILINE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx#BS_MULTILINE) to the styles you specify in the 4<sup>th</sup> argument of [`CreateWindowEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx).

As the documentation of [Button Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx) explains:

> **BS_MULTILINE**
>
> Wraps the button text to multiple lines if the text string is too long to fit on a single line in the button rectangle.

The `\n` characters inside the button text will then have the desired effect.

Check the screenshot on the [Button Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775947.aspx) page to see how it looks like.

Comment: Does that work for push buttons? (not saying it doesn't, I've never tried)

Comment: @JonathanPotter: yes, it does.  See the screenshot on [Button Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775947.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to a big multiline push button could be a command link button [BS_COMMANDLINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951#BS_COMMANDLINK). It has a main text and extra notes (setup via [BCM_SETNOTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775977) message or [Button_SetNote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761869) macro), shown in different size fonts. The fonts are predefined and cannot be changed as far as I know. There is also a default green arrow, which can be replaced with another image (via [BM_SETIMAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761822)), but cannot be removed entirely. However, the button background can be changed via [WM_CTLCOLORBTN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761849) message (this does not work for any other pushbutton), which can be quite handy sometimes, e.g. to blend with the window background like in toolbar.